# Problema al obtener el elemento DOM que dispara un evento con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo esta código script:

```
function eliminarTarea(e)
    {
        var id_tarea = this.children[0].getAttribute("data-id");

        var xhr;

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
            {
                var data = xhr.responseText;

                if(data == 1)
                {
                    var fila = e.currentTarget;
                    console.log(fila);
                }
                else
                    alert("No se pudo eliminar la tarea");
            }
        }

        xhr.open("POST", "lib/delete.php", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send("id_tarea=" + id_tarea);

        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Lo que trato de hacer es obtener el elemento que disparo el evento click que ejecuta esa función, lo que primero hago es validar que se haya eliminado de la base de datos para después proceder a quitarlo de la página web sin necesidad de recargarla, como no puedo acceder al elemento con tan solo poner la palabra reservada `this` entonces pensé que tal vez podría recuperar ese elemento a través del `objeto event` e investigando vi que con la propiedad `currentTarget` de este objeto se puede recuperar el elemento que disparo el evento.

El problema es que la propiedad `currentTarget` me devuelve un `null` en lugar de devolver el objeto que lanzó el evento.

```
 <ul class="lista" id="lista">
   <li><a href="">Tarea 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Tarea 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Tarea 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

A cada elemento `li` agrego el evento click que ejecuta la función `eliminarTarea`

Si `e.currentTarget`lo pongo fuera de `onreadystatechange` me devuelve el elemento que disparo el evento pero si lo pongo dentro me devuelve null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currentTarget obtiene el elemento que dispara el evento pero en tu funcion llamas a `this`:

ejemplo:

```js
function alerta(el){
 //obtenemos el texto del elemento clickeado
 let text = el.innerText;
 alert(`el elemento clickeado tiene texto "${text}"`)
}

document.querySelector("#lista").addEventListener("click",function(event){
    //evitamos el comportamiento por defecto del tag a
    event.preventDefault();
   // obtenemos del evento -> el elemento clickeado -> luego a su padre
  // evitamos que llame la funcion con elemetos que no sean LI
 if(event.target.parentElement.tagName == "LI" )
  //obtenemos del evento el elemento clickeado
  // y se lo pasamos a la funcion alerta()
   alerta(event.target);
});
```

```html
 <ul class="lista" id="lista">
   <li><a href="">Tarea 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Tarea 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Tarea 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Pero que no se supone que this se usa para obtener un elemento del DOM??

Comment: `this` hace referencia al objeto en donde se invoca te recomiendo leer esto [this](https://yeisondaza.com/entendiendo-this-javascript)